# Draw a semicircle / half circle in WPF / C#

Tags: c#, wpf, graphics, 2d, geometry

I need to draw a semicircle / half circle in WPF. Any idea how to do that? Thanks for any hint!

Answer (score 8):

Since the original link is dead, here's how I was able to draw an arc:

```
<Canvas>
    <Path Stroke="Gray">
        <Path.Data>
            <PathGeometry>
                <PathGeometry.Figures>
                    <PathFigureCollection>
                        <PathFigure StartPoint="0,20">
                            <PathFigure.Segments>
                                <PathSegmentCollection>
                                    <ArcSegment Size="20, 20"
                                    IsLargeArc="True"
                                    SweepDirection="CounterClockwise"
                                    Point="40,20" />
                                </PathSegmentCollection>
                            </PathFigure.Segments>
                        </PathFigure>
                    </PathFigureCollection>
                </PathGeometry.Figures>
            </PathGeometry>
        </Path.Data>
    </Path>
</Canvas>
```

That produces the following image (with added markings for some of the variables)

[image]

The XAML above is a modified version of the XAML found here:

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/drawing-arc-using-arcsegment-in-xaml/

Comment: I am a bit confused by these figures. If the Width is 20 and the height is 20, how is it possible that the Point for the ArcSegment has a 40 in its coordinates?

Comment: Thank you, I don't know how I missed that. I've updated the image to be correct.